# Data Driven Pages - Locator Map Zoom

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

I need to create a map series that highlights a single tax parcel on a 800 scale map.  On the same map, I have a separate data frame that zooms into the highlighted parcel. I'm trying to get it to where DDP will zoom into each individual parcel in the second data frame. However it needs to zoom to the parcel, and adjust scale to always have a tight zoom on the given parcel. The main frame MUST stay at 800 scale, and the smaller should always be a tight zoom on the parcel. I'm not having any trouble on the main frame, but how using DDP can I get it to auto zoom in on the parcel in the smaller data frame? I've attached a map example of What it should look like. [image]

Answer (score 4):

First thing, set up your Data driven pages on the inset map - then what you can do is in your data driven pages setup dialog - on the extent page - set the map extent to best fit - say 105%  - this way it will always zoom to the parcel of interest. On the other data frame - adjust you scale so it is fixed at 800.